# Bootstrap dropdown menu is being stubborn

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I'm trying to use Bootstrap to make a site, and I saw that there was a capability to make a dropdown menu, which I was planning on doing anyways, so I jumped on it.

I haven't been able to get it to work at all. I've searched around, re-arranged my jQuery link to be before Bootstrap's, double and triple checked that my code had the same base as w3schools' example, but I haven't gotten any action to come out of clicking the button. I even got to the point where I commented out my code and replaced it with their example, but even that didn't work.

In my css file (and I'll include a copy below), I have overridden the background and border properties of all div objects to none, or with a set border of "1px solid black" so I can see the bodies and where they're landing. I also overrode the top and bottom margins of the row class, since I was trying to have items bordered up against each other. I have deleted that part of the css file and reloaded the page to see if that was the issue, but it didn't change the issue.

Stripping my entire css file (and an empty script file I'm writing later) out doesn't fix the issue.

Stripping the extra bootstrap link that allows me to make all columns on the same row the same height doesn't work.

Stripping the integrity and crossorigin out of the main link doesn't work (I found the link like that, I figured I'd leave it at the maker's recommendation).

Stripping all three out at the same time doesn't work. And that's stripping it out with the example from w3schools, even. I got suspicious of a bad link, and used the CDN that w3schools suggested for 'minified css'. No improvement.

So I'm a little at wit's end and fairly out of my depth. I'm going to put up just the necessary html code (I've commented everything else out by now trying to test the thing anyways), and I'm going to include my css code for the title bar that it's in just for completeness, although, again, I did tear the whole file from the html document at some point. So I'd be very surprised if the issue was even css related outside of the CDN link.

html code (my dropdown menu code is commented out, the active code is from w3school's example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do Weekly List</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css" />
    <link href="format.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- <div class="dropdown" id="option-div">
        <button id="option-btn" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li id="pswd-change"><p>Change your password</p></li>
          <li id="end-user"><p>Delete your account</p></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li id="help"><p>Help</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div> -->
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example<span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
/*all div's, negating some of bootstrap's formatting*/
div {
  position: relative;
  background: none !important;
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}

/*bootstrap's row class*/
.row{
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

/*the button is within this title bar*/
#title-bar{
  background: #b3ffb3 !important;
  border: 2px solid grey !important;
}

/*This is the direct css for the button that's commented out*/
button#option-btn{
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-13/512/settings-128.png);
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 2rem;
}

/*the div item that held my button (commented out) and had class="dropdown"*/
#option-div{
  height: 6rem !important;
  width: 6rem !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

/*just for the header in the title bar
#header{
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: .50rem;
}
```

If anyone can see what's going on here, I'd really appreciate it. I'm hoping I've just been looking at this for far too long, and I'm missing something really small.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What is the expected result and what is the current result when running that code?

Comment: You might have better luck with Bootstrap's examples: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Your code works for me, but... where do you load Bootstrap JS?

Comment: @makshh right on the money. I hadn't yet, I didn't realize I needed to. I'm just coming back from plugging it in, and it works now.

Comment: @CharlieFish I was trying to get a dropdown menu, but I couldn't get the menu to actually drop down, it stayed hiding in the background and only the button showed. As I noted above, I hadn't realized I needed the javascript link, and as soon as I did and put it in, it started to work again.

Comment: @IanSibley glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: Thanks! @CharlieFish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. As luck would have it, I found the problem right after I posted this.

I hadn't seen anywhere that I needed both the css and the javascript links. Or at least, having just the css link didn't help inside the html code, only when I also added the javascript code link was I able to make the dropdown menus work from my previous code and from w3school.

Call me green, but this is the first time I've encountered Bootstrap.

Comment: Always refer to Bootstrap's documentation to avoid problems like this. http://getbootstrap.com/